# how to access protected getter setter in another package in java?

Tags: java

How to access protected getter setter in another package in java? If we make 2 different class files in different package and we add protected getter setter in each  the class, then how we will access them in another class file which is also in a different package?

Comment: With reflection

Comment: If they're not declared `public`, then they're not meant to be accessed in the manner you describe.

Comment: or make helper classes which provide access to the protected inherited methods

Comment: If you need to access them from another package, then don't make them protected maybe?

Comment: If keeping the fields protected is necessary, you could use messages in one way or another, for example through a shared queue in some kind of serialized form.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **reflection**

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {
    private int salary;

    public Test(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    private int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    private void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test - salary: " + salary;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Test test = new Test(100);
        System.out.println(test); // Test - salary: 100
        
        Class testClass = test.getClass();
        
        Method hiddenMethod = testClass.getDeclaredMethod("setSalary", int.class);
        hiddenMethod.setAccessible(true);
        hiddenMethod.invoke(test, 200);
        
        System.out.println(test); // Test - salary: 200
    }
}
```